# regex to search for a string between two slashes

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I have a question in bash shell scripting. I am looking to search a string between two slashes. Slash is a delimiter here.

Lets say the string is /one/two/, I want to be able to just pick up one.

How can i achieve this is in shell scripts? Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are probably at least 20 good options here, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Use the -F flag of `awk` to set the delimeter to `/`. Then you can print the first (`$2`) and second (`$3`) field from the line.

```
$ cat /my/file
/one/two/

$ awk -F/ '{print $2}' /my/file
one

$ awk -F/ '{print $3}' /my/file
two
```

If the string is in a variable, you can pipe it to awk.

```
#!/bin/bash
var=/one/two/
echo $var | awk -F/ '{print $2}'
echo $var | awk -F/ '{print $3}'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
path="/one/two/"  
path=${path#/}   # Remove leading /
path=${path%%/*} # Remove everything after first / 
echo "$path"     # Is now "one"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) regular expression:

```
$ str="/one/two/"
$ re="/([^/]*)/[^/]*/"
$ [[ $str =~ $re ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
one
$
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `cut`:

```
$ str="/one/two/"
$ echo "$str" | cut -d/ -f2
one
$
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert your string to an array, delimited with `/` and read the necessary element:

```
$ str="/one/two/"
$ IFS='/' a=( $str ) echo "${a[1]}"
one
$
```

Answer (score 1):

And a couple of more

```
> cut -f 2 -d "/" <<< "/one/two"
one
> awk -F "/" '{print $2}' <<< "/one/two"
one
> oldifs="$IFS"; IFS="/"; var="/one/two/"; set -- $var; echo "$2"; IFS="$oldifs"
one
```

Comment: +1 for `<<<` here-strings and `set --`.  You don't need to save `oldifs` if you use  a command-grouping `{ IFS="/"; var="/one/two/"; set -- $var; echo "$2"; }`